# "DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 10.2 but version 11.2 or higher is needed" Connection Problem with Oracle 10g with Python 3.8

Tags: cx-oracle

I am trying to connect Oracle 10g Database with the help of Python
I am Following these instruction from the website :
https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html
I am using
`-Oracle 10g express edition 10.2
-Python 3.8.3
-Oracle Instant Client vs. 12.1`

I have also tried with other version of oracle instant client from 19.1 to 9.1

My Python Script is:-

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('Shubho/Shubho@//localhost:1521/orcl')

print(con.version)
con.close()
```

But in the above script I am getting this error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 10.2 but version 11.2 or higher is needed
```

I have the set Path as:

`C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\instantclient-basic-nt-12.1.0.2.0\instantclient_12_1
C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your machine is setup so the 10.2 libraries are being loaded first.  If PATH is really OK, check for stray oci.dll files that may be somewhere in the system directories.

Also, there is an 18c versions of Express Edition available.

Comment: Ok i have set the Path variable of oracle folder, now the problem solved. Thanks  For the Help